# Regexp excluding '\r\n'

Tags: regex

I have a string:

```
\r\ndsadasdsad\das\rdasdsacxz\ndasdsa\r\nadsadas\e
```

I want to make a regexp that will match all characters with '\' in front of them, but not "\r\n", so it would be '\.' without '\r\n'

Comment: [possibly helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: What programming language are you using for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\\r(?!\\n)|(?<!\\r)\\n|\\[^rn]
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/qV2mN4)

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match a single character that is preceded by a `\`, but is not part of the sequence `\r\n`:

```
(?:(?<!\\)|(?!r\\n))(?:(?<!\\r\\)|(?!n))(?<=\\).
```

You can find an explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/rX5eR2).

Answer (score -1):

This will match all characters which are not "n" or "r" and which have a slash in front of them.

```
(?<=\\)[^rn]
```

Comment: So it will not match \r or \n separately - I want them to be matched if they not occur together. Only when there's '\r\n' I want them not to be matched.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this should do what you're asking.. :

As per your question this matches `"ALL characters with '\' in front of them, but not '\r\n'"`

Test String:

```
\r\ndsadasdsad\das\rdasdsacxz\ndasdsa\r\nadsadas\e
```

Regex:

```
(?:\\r\\n\w*)|(\w+)
```

Matches:

```
MATCH 1 'das'

MATCH 2 'rdasdsacxz'

MATCH 3 'ndasdsa'

MATCH 4 'e'
```

Here's an example:  http://regex101.com/r/lE7gI7